# How to use the NSTimer inside of the for loop iphone?

Tags: iphone, for-loop, nstimer, icalendar

Am very new to iPhone application development. Am adding the events to iCal from my iphone app. The user can add multiple events at a time to iCal from the app. If the user add above 50 events to iCal, the event does not adding in iCal and the app getting crash. So, i want to avoid the app crash. So, i planned to delay the adding event to iCal inside the for loop(While the loop is in running state). How can i pause the  For loop running and continue the for loop after 10 sec's delay. Meanwhile the for loop should continue after 10 sec's from where it was paused. How can i do this? Any ideas? Please help to solve my problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do what you're after is an `NSOperationQueue` but it's a bit technical. Something like this might be easier to understand:

Header:

```
NSMutableArray *events;
```

When you specify your list of events:

```
events = /*....*/;
[self nextOp];
```

The `nextOp` method:

```
-(void)nextOp {
    // Do 10 events at a time.
    int stop = MIN(10,[events count]);
    for (int i = 0; i < stop; i++) {
        //Add [events objectAtIndex:i] to iCal
    }

    // Remove these processed events.
    [events removeObjectsInRange:NSMakeRange(0,stop)];
    if ([events count] > 0) {
        // We've still got more events to go, so schedule our next call
        [self performSelector:@selector(nextOp) withObject:nil afterDelay:10];
    } else {
        [events release];
        events = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for spot response. I will incorporate your idea in my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should **not** pause loops on iOS.  If you cannot complete your processing promptly and synchronously, you should exit the loop and exit the method containing the loop.

To complete your loop's processing, your app should start another iteration of the loop later, such as in a callback from a completion delegate, a timer, a performselector, or an operation queue.  The latter methods can include a delay.  You will have to know how to unstructure loops and how to save local state to do this.  Exiting a loop with a callback in place is roughly equivalent to a delayed "GOTO" statement.

For an NSTimer call to be useful in loop processing, you need to exit your loop and method, as only then will the timer's callback selector be called.